# How to pass json object in angular 5 delete method

Tags: angular

```
deletekeystore(deletekeystore: Deletekeystore) {
    console.log("KeyStoreContext@@@@@@@@@");
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + '/deletekeystore', deletekeystore);
}
```

I am getting error while I am passing the object in this method

Comment: what is a error can you show us

Comment: for a http DELETE, there is no body to the request. Usually  you use some id *in the url*.

Comment: what is saying your API documentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can only pass URL to `delete` http method. You may want to try using `put` or `post` (and change API accordingly).

Comment: Change the API method to `put` instead of `delete` and then use `put` from client and pass the object.